# One input element, one ng-model attribute, with multiple directives

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Goal: create an isolate-scoped directive that, when applied to an `input` element with an existing `ng-model` directive, constrains the value of the model arbitrarily, reflecting the changes back to the parent scope.  Do all of this with "controller-as" naming.

For example, this template represents a possible use of the aforementioned directive, assuming the containing controller is `outerCtrl`:

```
<input ng-model="outerCtrl.value" my-directive>
```

Where the following represents a portion of the definition for `myDirective` (absent the functional pieces, which are represented as comments and are the actual question at hand):

```
angular.module('app').directive('myDirective', [function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {},
    require: 'ngModel',
    controllerAs: 'myCtrl',
    bindToController: true,
    controller: controller: [function() {
      var vm = this;
      vm.magicValue = 'foo';
    }],

    // ----------
    // Insert appropriate compile, link, etc. to ensure that if
    // the user ever types the "magic value" in the input, then
    // the parent model (outerCtrl.value) is set with the magic
    // value; otherwise, the value set on the parent model should
    // be "null" or "undefined."  And, of course, if there is ever
    // a programmatic setting of outerCtrl.value, that should be
    // reflected down to the input while obeying the same rule -
    // i.e., if some value other than the magic value is set, it
    // should be ignored.
    //
    // Of critical importance: there may be other directives
    // operating on the same ng-model within the isolate scope
    // (or, rather, as child scopes of the isolate scope).
    // These other directives should work in concert with
    // myDirective.  For example, one such directive might be a
    // "typeahead" directive that manipulates the model based on
    // selection from a dropdown list.  This behavior can't be
    // trampled by myDirective.
    // ----------

  };
}]);
```

My primary motivation in using isolate scope is to ensure that the directive is reusable.  And my motivation in not using a wrapper `div` or other element to contain an `input` in the directive's template is to make it easier to use the directive on any existing `input` element, thereby also taking advantage of ng-model validation that might already be working in the parent scope.

Is this possible?  More importantly, should I even be attempting this, or is it a misuse of ng-model/isolate scopes/directives per the intentions of the framework designers?

Comment: Requesting isolate scope from multiple directives on the same element is not allowed.